# AOSP build for Samsung Galaxy Tab A

Tags: open-source, android-source, samsung-galaxy

Would like to build my own pure AOSP project. Have successfully built LineageOS 14.1 but would like to do the same with a pure AOSP. I dont need any features or anything that Lineage or CM offers.

The git i was using to build LOS is here:
https://github.com/Valera1978/android_device_samsung_gtaxlwifi/tree/cm-14.1

The problem I have is I do not know how I need to modify an existing LineageOS device tree to be able to compile for a pure AOSP project.
Tried to get in touch with the maintainer of that git, but my question is either too complex or too basic as he simply ignored it.

Alternatively, is there any way to get an original device tree source from anywhere? Tried to look it up from "samsung open source" but couldnt find anything.

Any solutions?

The tablet is a Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this git repo is just a directory in aosp tree , for getting the Android source code from google website. and add this repository and kernel to this source code.

and answer to your question is :

> There is no official or unofficial android source repository for any device from Samsung

**Update**

you can definitely use device tree in aosp , because in Arm-Platform device tree files are associated with kernel , if the kernel is ok than you can use device tree

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This repo is the "device tree" directory itself and is not for AOSP but for LineageOS 14.1. Have downloaded LineageOS source code and added this "device tree" with the "kernel" and "vendor" directory together and successfully compiled a LineageOS 14.1 version for my device. My question is, can this very same directory be used to compile it with AOSP or needs to be modified? I guess the kernel and the vendor directories definately can be used, but what about the "device tree"? Thanks